# Cannot Insert HTML on var using getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to insert an HTML using my controller to a div, but I do not know what is wrong with my JS code, it always return Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. Is there anything I missed?

My Controller:

```
$this->load->model('model_admin','modeladmin');

$branchid = $this->input->post('subject_branchid');

$classdata = $this->modeladmin->getclassesviabranch('169APC00002');

$selectoption = "";

foreach ($classdata as $classitems)
{

    $selectoption .= "<option value='".$classitems['class_id']."'>".$classitems['class_name']."</option>";
}
```

echo $selectoption;

My View

```
<select class="form-control" id="subject_branchid" name="subject_branchid" style="width:50%;" onchange="getvalues()">

    <?php

        foreach ($branches as $branch)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$branch['branch_id']."'>".$branch['branch_prefix']."</option>";
        }

    ?>

</select>

<br>
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" />
<br>


<select class="form-control" id="subject_classid" name="subject_classid" style="width:50%;">

    <div id="htmlcontainer" name="htmlcontainer"></div>

</select>
```

My JS

```
<script>
function getvalues() 
{
    //get the value of the select when it changes
    var value = $("#subject_branchid").val()

    //make an ajax request posting it to your controller
    $.post('<?=site_url("admin/test")?>', {data:value},function(result) 
    {
    //change the input price with the returned value
    //$('#price').val(result);
    document.getElementById('#htmlcontainer').innerHTML = '<h1>Something</h1>';
    });
};
```

Comment: You cannot have a `div` element within a `select` element. The only valid elements inside a `select` are `option` and `optgroup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the hash `#`.use `#` when you use jquery to select element by id.

```
 document.getElementById('htmlcontainer')
```

if you are using jquery then you should use # ( for id)

`$('#htmlcontainer').html('text');`

**edit**

another problem

you have added div tags inside select tag directly.select tag cannot have div tags directly only `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements are allowed.so you have to change it.

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: I still get the same  error even without the #

Comment: @DeviantMark well.first open the page in browser then using inspect element or sourcecode check is  `<div id="htmlcontainer"`  exist?

Comment: yes it exists, here is the  code

    <select class="form-control" id="subject_classid" name="subject_classid" style="width:50%;">
           
<div id="mydiv" name="htmlcontainer"></div>
          
          </select>

Comment: @DeviantMark `htmlcontainer` is name not the id.either use `document.getElementById('mydiv')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('htmlcontainer')[0];` 0 should be correct index.why did you post `<div id="htmlcontainer" name="htmlcontainer"></div>` in your post there is different code

Comment: changed it, still I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @DeviantMark what did you change ?

Comment: Here is my jsFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/v1j62ufa/

Comment: @DeviantMark https://jsfiddle.net/v1j62ufa/2/ i removed php codes.then i got same error.problem is you have added div tags inside select tag.select tag cannot have div tags directly.only option tags are allowed

Comment: Thanks I got it working, but I got another bump, the $.post seems to be not passing data to my controller...

Comment: @DeviantMark you should echo it. `<?echo site_url("admin/test")?>`

Comment: So  I should change `$.post('<?=site_url("admin/test")?>', {data:value},function(result)` to `<?echo site_url("admin/test")?>`? I tried it and got this from the console  url_link/admin/%3C?%20echo%20site_url(%22admin/test%22)?%3E 404 not found

Comment: @DeviantMark hmm missing php tag `<?php echo site_url("admin/test");?>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: @DeviantMark my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and remove the hash symbol `#`, so it looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('htmlcontainer').innerHTML = '<h1>Something</h1>';
```

If you think about it, what you're trying to do is to fetch an element with an ID of `#htmlcontainer`, which doesn't exist.

In jQuery however, you use the `#` symbol.

Comment: I still get the same  error even without the #