# No Jquery -- Javascript can´t see my id:s even when i have script in body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I write javascript in my body tag it returns null on my id:s. 
If I create element in javascript it find the id but not when i create it in body(html). If I write in JQuery it finds it to. But I want to write it in plain javascript if it comes up on my test. It's frustrating. I tried window on load and put the code under body tag but it haven´t worked. I understand that the code not find it because it thinks that it´s not created but how do I get the code to see that I have created for example a div in html?

```js
document.getElementById("#btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var obj = {
    FirstName: document.getElementBydId("#firstName").value,
    LastName: document.getElementBydId("#lastName").value,
    Address: document.getElementBydId("#address").value,
    Phone: document.getElementBydId("#phone").value,
    Zip: document.getElementBydId("#zip").value,
  };
  txtToDiv(obj);
});

function txtToDiv(obj) {
  var d = getElementById("#d");
  d.innerHtml = obj.LastName + " " + obj.FirstName + "<br>" +
    obj.Zip + " " + obj.Address + "<br>" + obj.Phone
};
```

```css
.container{ margin: auto;background-color: lightgrey;width: 500px;height: 400px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Förnamn: <input id="firstName"/>
  Efternamn: <input id="lastName"/><br/>
  Zip: <input id="zip"/>
  adress: <input id="address"/><br/>
  Telefon: <input id="phone"/><br/>
  <button id="btn">Flytta</button>
</div>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Remove the `#`.

Comment: `getElementBydId` this function already knows you are looking for id, no need to add the `#` to the name like in jquery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Insert HTML on var using getElementById](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381181/cannot-insert-html-on-var-using-getelementbyid)

Comment: Also, I always create a function to use as a short-cut for typing out `document.getElementById`, which gets pretty tedious pretty quickly. E.g `function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}` - this then allows you to type `byId('firstName').value` etc, etc - If you _do_ wish to use CSS selectors in vanilla javascript, you may wish to look at the `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` functions, which return a single (the first) element and an array (even if only 1 exists) of them.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I remove #. :-)

Comment: @enhzflep Worth noting that it’s not an `Array` array but a `NodeList`. Another tip: when I need to make an object or array with multiple elements selected by ID, I first write an array with only the IDs as strings, then `map` it to `document.getElementById(…)`. Much more elegant.

Comment: @MariaKällström If it still doesn’t work, use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors.

Comment: @Xufox Yes. I did that and it says that I can´t do a eventlistener on a null value.

Comment: @Xufox - ahh yes, thanks for pointing that out. I'd long since forgotten I've got a `forEach` function that I use for all array-_like_ collections. Good tip re: the use of `map` - I don't recall the last time I wanted to do that, but do need to iterate `NodeList`s and `HtmlCollection`s all the time, hence the `forEach` func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var obj = {
        FirstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
        LastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
        Address: document.getElementById("address").value,
        Phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
        Zip: document.getElementById("zip").value,
    };
    txtToDiv(obj);
});

function txtToDiv(obj) {
    var d = document.getElementById("d");
    d.innerHTML = obj.LastName + " " + obj.FirstName + "<br>" +
        obj.Zip + " " + obj.Address + "<br>" + obj.Phone
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Förnamn: <input id="firstName"/>
    Efternamn: <input id="lastName"/><br/>
    Zip: <input id="zip"/>
    adress: <input id="address"/><br/>
    Telefon: <input id="phone"/><br/>
    <button id="btn">Flytta</button>
</div>
    <div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think you solved it. Some misspelling and # :-)

Comment: @MariaKällström wheres thumbs up? :)

Comment: I can´t, to low rep :-(.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some typos in your code, also, to select an element by id there's no `#` needed as `document.getElementById()` already looks for an element by its id.. You can make your life easier by selecting all `inputs` within the container and use their ids as property names. So you don't need to hardcode everything multiple times. In your `txtToDiv` function, you can also just loop over the passed object properties.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var obj = {};
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".container input"), function(e) {
    obj[e.id] = e.value;
  });
  txtToDiv(obj);
});

function txtToDiv(obj) {
  var d = document.getElementById("d");
  d.innerHTML = Object.keys(obj).map(function(v) { return obj[v]; }).join(" ");
};
```

```css
.container{ margin: auto;background-color: lightgrey;width: 500px;height: 400px;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Förnamn: <input id="firstName"/>
  Efternamn: <input id="lastName"/><br/>
  Zip: <input id="zip"/>
  adress: <input id="address"/><br/>
  Telefon: <input id="phone"/><br/>
  <button id="btn">Flytta</button>
</div>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a good practice to encapsulate your javascript code in

```
window.onload = function(){
    // your code goes here
}
```

also use `document.getElementByID('myId')` instead of `#myId`

Comment: And even better practise to get into the habit of using `.addEventListener('eventName', functionName, boolBubbles)`, since you can attach multiple handlers to a single event (and later remove any of them). Not so important with the load event of the document, but good practise all the same. :)

Comment: already tried that. It didn´t work. But perhaps document.onload

Comment: @MariaKällström - you can attach to the window's onload event. I use the following: `window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);` followed by a function, `function onDocLoaded(evt){ .... };` (You remove the 'on' part of the event name when attaching, thus onclick --> click, onmousemove --> mousemove etc, etc)